# Expansion of the 4 points Liouville conformal blocks in terms of the intermediate dimension

Tags: conformal-field-theory

Thanks to AGT conjecture, 4 points Liouville conformal blocks $\mathcal{F}\left[\begin{matrix}\theta_1,\theta_{t}\\ \theta_{\infty},\theta_0
\end{matrix};\sigma,z\right]$ are known explicitly as power series in the anharmonic ratio $z$.

Is there any other expansion available with respect to the intermediate conformal dimension $\sigma$? If not, do we have informations on the dependence of the expansion (polynomial, etc...)?

Comment: 1) How the conformal blocks in Liouville theory are any different from conformal blocks in any other theory? 2) See 1987 paper by Zamolodchikov on recursion relations for Virasoro conformal blocks. In short, the block is a meromorphic function of $\sigma$ with residues proportional to other blocks, and a known form of an essential singularity at $\sigma=\infty$.

Comment: Also, just in case, how to compute Virasoro conformal block have been known long before AGT.